# How to trigger a Vue method when computed property changes

Tags: vue.js, vuex, computed-properties

Essentially, in a Vue application, I have a page that lists Contacts. And a search form that is part of a header component. I capture the input search term as a state variable in the vuex store and track it as a computed variable.

I have a method to retrieve contacts that is called within the mounted hook. I want to call the same getContacts method again whenever the state search variable changes. Using a watcher to do this atm, but I have read that watching a computed value is not the right way. Wondering if there is a better way to do this. Script below.

```
<script>
  import API from '@/utils/Api.js'

    ...

    export default ({
        ...
        tableData: [],
            }
        },
    computed: {
      search() {
        return this.$store.getters.search;
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.getContacts();
    },
    methods: {
      async getContacts() {
        try {
          const {data} = await API.get('/contacts?search=' + this.search)
          this.tableData = data
          } catch (e) {
          console.error(e)
        }
      }
    },

    watch: {
      search () {
        this.getContacts();
      }
    }
  })

</script>
```

Comment: if this component is doing side effects based on `$store.getters.search` updates then a watch seems sensible. A watch could also be this `'$store.getters.search'(){this.getContacts();}`

Answer (score 1):

Try to watch directly the state item and then pass the new value as parameter for the method, then use `immediate:true` to replace the mounted hook call :

```js
  export default ({
        ...
        tableData: [],
            }
        },
    methods: {
      async getContacts(val) {
        try {
          const {data} = await API.get('/contacts?search=' + val)
          this.tableData = data
          } catch (e) {
          console.error(e)
        }
      }
    },

    watch: {
      '$store.getters.search': {
       handler(newVal)
        this.getContacts(newVal);
       },
        immediate:true
      }
    }
  })
```